# How to suggest that I'm sumarizing the previous text?

Tags: sentence-starts

I am writting a scientific paper. It goes like this:

> Statement 1 (citation). Statement 2 (citation). Statement 3
>   (citation). **Overall**, the evidence in literature shows that ...

So with the "Overall, ", I want to suggest that I want to summarize the previous text. Is the word "Overall" good for this purpose or is there a  better way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will work; however, if you want to publish your paper, you should look at the journal's style guide to see if there's any requirement for something else.

Comment: 'Overall' works, as does 'In summary', 'To conclude', 'Ergo', and other synonyms.